# is it possible to stack 2 bars, layer on top of each other (not above each other)?

Tags: bar-chart, recharts, stacked-bar-chart

Trying to build a bar chart where each bar is essentially 2 bars layered on top of each other, and the top-most bar will be thinner than the bottom bar.

I see the existing feature where if you provide a "stackId", it stacks it, but it is stacked above it, which isn't what I want.

I've been trying to customize a bar shape that supports this, but failing to do so.

What makes this more tricky is, we're using log scaling for the Y axis.

Any input on this would greatly be appreciated!

EDIT: Attaching a mock of what I'm trying to do:

layered bar chart

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. That certainly is possible. While rendering multiple Bar elements, they will be put on a single axis next to each other.

The trick is to use multiple x-axes. To show how this works, I added a new story to the Recharts storybook.

You can find the code for it in this [PR](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/pull/3371) and soon in the repo itself.
For the sake of a complete answer, I am duplicating the code here.

```
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
        <BarChart data={data}>
          <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="green" xAxisId="one" barSize={50} />
          <XAxis xAxisId="one" />
          {/* The smaller bar must be rendered in front of the larger one to be visible. */}
          <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="red" xAxisId="two" barSize={30} />
          <XAxis xAxisId="two" hide />
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image]

Comment: This is now merged - find the live example [here](https://master--63da8268a0da9970db6992aa.chromatic.com/?path=/story/api-chart-barchart--bar-in-bar)